# Как обновить порядок колонки не используя sequence и setval в posgresql

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть такая таблица с таким порядком[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нам нужно сделать, чтобы все строки были по порядку (Order колонка) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И сделать это нужно не используя sequence!

Comment: А зачем? Сам принцип запроса - если не задаешь конкретный ORDER BY то не должен предполагать порядок - т.е. записи от запроса к запросу могут возвращаться в произвольном порядке. Сортировка или прямым указанием - или на стороне клиента. В целом - не представляю ситуации когда подобная сортировка может потребоваться (1% оставляю на идиотские требования нумерации в официальных документах). И зачем такие ограничения - не использовать встроенные средства PostgreSQL?

Comment: Представьте ситуацию, у нас строгий порядок колонок таблиц. И мы удаляем 1 элемент из таблицы. Соответственно сбивается порядок. 
Было такой порядок (1, 2, 3, 4), а стал (1, 2, 4). Нужно сделать так, чтобы порядок стал (1, 2, 3)

Comment: Порядок хранения в БД не имеет никакого значения. Отображение при выводе - да. Но тогда можно реализовать это на стороне клиента (это просто). Да и к слову: Вам нужен порядок колонок или порядок записей - это разные вещи? Вообще - хранить порядок записей в БД - моветон. Почитайте например описание нормальных форм (https://habr.com/ru/articles/193756/) . Скорее всего у Вас допущен косяк именно при проектировании системы (нарушение 1-й нормальной формы). В любом случае - повторю вопрос, а в чем проблема использования последовательностей Postgre?

Answer (score 1):

Функция PostgreSQL `ROW_NUMBER()` создана именно для вашего сценария.

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TPIcJIEe)

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, начало
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID uuid PRIMARY KEY, OrderNo INT, FirstName VARCHAR(20)); --uuid
INSERT INTO tbl (ID, OrderNo, FirstName) VALUES
('5D4B09BF-D3A6-4237-8E74-48D9EA20465B', 1, 'Вася'),
('36944B2A-4DB5-40BE-AC66-E75FD58BCADA', 3, 'Петя'),
('655CA3E4-EDB6-4475-9AD4-F320B67F83C8', 4, 'Сережа');
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, конец

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderNo ASC) AS seq, *
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT ID, seq, FirstName
FROM rs
ORDER BY seq;
```

**Результат**

| ID | seq | FirstName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5D4B09BF-D3A6-4237-8E74-48D9EA20465B | 1 | Вася |
| 36944B2A-4DB5-40BE-AC66-E75FD58BCADA | 2 | Петя |
| 655CA3E4-EDB6-4475-9AD4-F320B67F83C8 | 3 | Сережа |